# Expo Android App Build Stuck on Axios Request

Tags: react-native, axios, httprequest, expo

I have built this pizza app in which the home screen loads data that it received using axios get request. When I use the app on the development mode i.e. running expo client on my phone and scanning the QR code, the app loads pizza cards with no issues. (PS there is a loading screen before the pizza cards render). But when I ran expo build:android and got the standalone app (apk file). I installed it on my phone and the home screen is stuck on the loading sign. It is not fetching any data from the backend API, can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error is that I was registering for expo notification and calling the api only after the promise resolved (I forgot to provide FCM api key)

for eg:-

```
registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => {

//--- calling the login api ---

}
```

since expo notification will not work in production build if we dont provide FCM key thats why login api was not getting called in production so my request was working in development but not in production